# image loader works only once in a link within a loop

Tags: php, javascript

I have a php script with a link inside a for statement. I was trying to use an image loader (.gif) each time the user pressing the link. The link refers to a number I use for pagination. With the use of the for statement the link displays links like :1 ,2 ,3... wich are respectively the page 1, 2, 3 ...etc. If the user press on 2, to move from page 1 to 2, the image loader works succesfully. But if the user press on 3, 4, ...etc the image loader stop working. Any idea how I can fix it?

This is my php script:

```
$per_page=1;    

if(!isset($_GET['page'])){
$page=1;
}else{
$page = $_GET['page'];
}

if($page<=1)
$start=0;
else
$start = ($page * $per_page) - $per_page;


    $sql = " SELECT `name`, `surname`, `email`, `user_id` FROM users WHERE (surname LIKE '$name%' AND name LIKE '$surname%') OR (surname LIKE '$surname%' AND name LIKE '$name%') ";

    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql));
    $num_pages = ceil($num_rows / $per_page);


$number=1;  //image loader called for a link inside for statement

    for($number; $number<=$num_pages; $number +=1)
    {
    if($number <= 10){

            if($page==$number){
                echo" &nbsp; $number &nbsp; ";  
            }else 
                echo" <a href='?value=$value&page=$number'  id='loading' >$number</a> "; 
    }else if ($page>=10){

            if($page==$number)
            echo"&nbsp;&nbsp;... <b>$number</b> ";

        }
    }


echo" &nbsp;&nbsp; <img src='img/loader.gif' class='loading' style='display:none;'  />";
```

and this is my javascript:

```
<script>
$("#loading2").click(function () {
        $(".loading").show();
});
</script>
```

Comment: id `loading2` does not exist.

Comment: If you want to refer to only one object, is prefered to refer to its `id`, use a class instead for more than one, as @ElmoVanKielmo sayd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is here:

```
<a href='?value=$value&page=$number'  id='loading' >$number</a>
```

`id` attribute must be unique in the HTML document.
Most browsers will select only first element with the matching `id` and other anchors won't have `onclick` event handler bound.

Use class:

```
<a href='?value=$value&page=$number'  class='loading-anchor' >$number</a>

<script>
$(".loading-anchor").click(function () {
        $(".loading").show();
});
</script>
```